# Pyspark Counter based on column condition

Tags: pyspark, counter, lag

Hello I would like to create a new column with a counter based on the condition of Tag1 column.

I have this:

| Time | Tag1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 0 |

And I would like this:

| Time | Tag1 | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | 4 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 0 | 0 |

I tried with function.when(df.Tag1 == 1, function.lag(df.Tag1)+1).otherwise(0) but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Window function

```
    new = (df.withColumn('Counter',(col('Tag1')=='0'))#Create Bool
       .withColumn('Counter', F.sum(F.col('Counter').cast('integer')).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))# Create Group by summing bool
.withColumn('Counter', when(col('Tag1')==0, col('Tag1')).otherwise(F.sum('Tag1').over(Window.partitionBy('Counter').orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))))#Conditionally add
       
      )

new.show()

+----+----+-------+
|Time|Tag1|Counter|
+----+----+-------+
|   1|   0|      0|
|   2|   1|      1|
|   3|   1|      2|
|   4|   1|      3|
|   5|   0|      0|
|   6|   0|      0|
|   7|   1|      1|
|   8|   1|      2|
|   9|   1|      3|
|  10|   1|      4|
|  11|   0|      0|
|  12|   0|      0|
+----+----+-------+
```